# Grid View doesn't appear at screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, frontend, aspxgridview

why My GridView was not displaying?

ascx CODE:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcGridTest" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="grdTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"/>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

ascx.cs CODE:

```
protected void btnPesquisar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string placa = string.Empty;
    insereParameterPlaca(txtPlaca.Text.ToUpper(), out placa);

    string transportadora = string.Empty;
    transportadora = insereTransportadoraSelecionada();

    string tiposWorkflow = string.Empty;
    insereTiposWorkflow(chkBox_TiposOcorrencia.Items, out tiposWorkflow);

    string cliente = string.Empty;
    insereCliente(out cliente);

    string query = string.Empty;
    query = string.Format(SQL_GET_OCORRENCIAS_PARAMETRIZADO, placa, transportadora, tiposWorkflow, cliente);

    using (var sqlDataAccess = new MSQLDataAccess(Util.GetIntegraConnectionString))
    {
        var datatable = sqlDataAccess.GetDataTable(query);

        grdTest.Visible = true;
        grdTest.DataSource = datatable;
        grdTest.DataBind();

    }
}
```

AutoGenarateColuns was marked as false and I'm runnig DataBind() command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`, if you don't want to specify each column.